# References for involutive systems of vector fields?

Tags: reference-request

Can anyone recommend me references dealing with **involutive systems of vector fields**?

I'm taking a course which is using the book **An Introduction to Involutive Structures** (F. Berhanu, J. Hounie, P. Cordaro), it's a survey of the last 25 years in the subject, however I find it hard to follow.

There is also the book **Hypo-analytic structures** (F. Treves) however I don't have access to it and I can't buy it too.

If someone could recommend me other books (lecture notes...) apart from the two above I would appreciate.

Thanks